# Checking for the polynomial

Tags: polynomials

You are given $N$ integers and an integer $K$. How can I determine if there exists a polynomial $f(x)$ with degree at most $K$ such that for each $1\le i\le n$, $f(i) = a[i]$

Like suppose we have $K=3$ and $N=5$ with integers $[0,1,2,3,4]$ then here answer will be "YES" as The polynomial $f(x)=x-1$ satisfies the given data,also the degree of $f(x)\le3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to find the unique polynomial of degree $\le K$ with $f(i)=a_i$ for $1\le i\le K+1$ and check the remaining values.
A simple algorithm to do so (without actually exhibiting the polynomial) is as follows: Write down $a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_N$. Then in the next row write down the $N-1$ differences $a_2-a_1, a_3-a_2,\ldots, a_N-a_{N-1}$. Repeat with the third row having the differences of the second and so on. If the $(K+2)$th row is all zeroes (or equivalently row $K+1$ is constant), an interpolating polynomial of degree $\le K$ as required exists.

Comment: Could you please explain in context of above example?

Comment: @user3001932 If the initial row is $[0,1,2,3,4]$ the second row is $[1,1,1,1]$ and the third is $[0,0,0]$. Since row $3$ is all zeroes, there is a polynomial of degree $K=3-2=1$ that interpolates the original date.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the polynomial as $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_Kx^K$. Now substitute each pair $(i, a_i)$ to get one equation to each. If the system of $N$ equations in $K$ variables is solvable, you get the polynomial. If not, there is no such polynomial at all.

In your example: you have the polynomial $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$. putting each point gives:

- $a_0+a_1\cdot1+a_2\cdot1^2+a_3\cdot1^3=0$
- $a_0+a_1\cdot2+a_2\cdot2^2+a_3\cdot2^3=1$
- $a_0+a_1\cdot3+a_2\cdot3^2+a_3\cdot3^3=2$
- $a_0+a_1\cdot4+a_2\cdot4^2+a_3\cdot4^3=3$
- $a_0+a_1\cdot5+a_2\cdot5^2+a_3\cdot5^3=4$

Which the solution is $a_0=-1$, $a_1=1$ and $a_2,a_3$ can get any value.

Comment: Did u read the question carefully?I am given a K also.Secondly i just need to check not to find the polynomial.Is their any method in which i need not to calculate the polynomial

Comment: @user3001932 It is the best way I know. You also don't always have to solve the system of equations to know if it is solvable. The $K$ was mistakely replaced by $n$, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take a polynomial $f$ of degree $K$. Then

$$ f(i) = a_i,\quad i=1,...,n $$

is a linear system of $n$-equations with the $K+1$ coefficients of $f$ as unknowns.

To study the existence of solutions for the unknowns, recognize that square sub-matrices of the system matrix are of type [Vandermonde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) (see Applications section of the link).